# Optional parameterised swift framework method in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I have framework which I developed in swift and I am using that framework in my objective C code base.

In Framework I have below class and method

```
public class MyClass: NSObject {
    public func testMethod(typeId : Int?){
    }
}
```

When I change typeId **Int?** optional to **Int** then I am able to access that **testMethod** in Objective C but with **Int?** optional paramter I am not able to access that **testMethod** in my Objective C code. Any idea how can I access optional swift parameterised method in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

try override your method like this:

```
public class MyClass: NSObject {
    //this method can be called only from swift and can recieve nil
    public func testMethod(typeId : Int?){
    }
    //this method can be called from swift and objective c but both can´t recieve nil instead you can send 0 or another value and check it 
    public func testMethod(typeId : Int){ // override method

          testMethod(typeId:typeId == 0 ? nil : ticketId) //original method
    }
}
```